# Merge partial mirror into reprepro distribution

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, deb, reprepro

I'm looking to include a few packages from an ubuntu mirror into my own custom apt repository.

#### Context:

Using Reprepro, I currently have the following distribution:

```
Origin: Private Repository
Label: Private Repository
Description: Private Repository
Suite: production
Codename: trusty
Components: main
Architectures: amd64
SignWith: A1AAA1A
```

Our custom package gets included with:

```
reprepro -b . includedeb trusty <packagename>
```

#### Problem:

What I'm looking to do is to add the libre2-1 packages from `http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/` into the same distribution, but I can't figure out how to do this. My hunch is that I need to configure `conf/updates` to mirror the repository, using a FilterList to define the packages I want, but I can't figure out how to get reprepro to parse the mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the best answer is a working example

1. Configuration files

   `conf/distributions`

   ```
   Codename: trusty
   Components: main universe
   Architectures: amd64
   #Update: test1
   Pull: pull1

   Codename: vivid
   Suite: production
   Components: universe
   Architectures: amd64
   Update: update1
   ```

   `conf/updates`

   ```
   Name: test1
   Suite: trusty
   Method: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   Components: main
   Architectures: amd64
   VerifyRelease: blindtrust
   FilterList: deinstall list

   Name: update1
   Suite: vivid
   Method: http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   VerifyRelease: blindtrust
   Components: universe
   Architectures: amd64
   FilterList: deinstall list1
   ```

   `conf/pulls`

   ```
   Name: pull1
   From: vivid
   FilterList: deinstall list1
   ```

   Lists have same format of `dpkg --get-selections > list`

   `conf/list`

   ```
   gedit                       install
   geany                       deinstall
   ```

   `conf/list1`

   ```
   libre2-1    install
   ```
2. Commands needed:

   ```
   reprepro update trusty
   reprepro update vivid
   reprepro pull trusty
   ```

   For short, you can run:

   ```
   reprepro update
   reprepro pull
   ```